# opensmtpd package installs mysql config files on 18.04

Tags: apt

On a fresh Ubuntu 18.04.3 instance I noticed that...

```bsh
sudo apt-get install opensmtpd
```

... also installed these MySQL config files:

- `/etc/mysql/conf.d/mysql.cnf`
- `/etc/mysql/conf.d/mysqldump.cnf`
- `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`
- `/etc/mysql/my.cnf.fallback`

While their contents seems to be harmless in itself, even more so because I do not have MySQL installed yet, I wonder if these will interfere with a later `apt-get install mysql-server` should I want to do that at some point? If so, would it be better to install `mysql-server` first?

Is it known if these files should be in the package at all, and if so, why?

The version installed is `opensmtpd@6.0.3p1-1build1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been figured out:

The files get installed as part of [`mysql-common`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/mysql-common) which is a dependency of [`libmysqlclient20`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/libmysqlclient20) which is a dependency of [`opensmtpd-extras`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/opensmtpd-extras) which is a *recommended*-dependency of [`opensmtpd`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/opensmtpd).

Hence, they will interfere with neither a later- nor earlier `apt-get install mysql-server` which will simply pull `mysql-common` in as well.

I've adopted to include `--no-install-recommends` as part of the `apt-get install -no-install-recommends opensmtpd` invocation as a working solution since the `opensmtpd-extras` are not needed afaict.